# Avoid new line (<br/>) when pasting data to MSExcel

Tags: html, sql-server, database, excel

I'm trying to paste some of my data from SQL Server to an Excel file. I have a field which accepts texts and html (Comments). It has some values contain `<br/>`. When I copy that record and paste in Excel, text in that field break the format of the table. 
Lines are breaking at the each `<br/>` tag and create new line between records. Please help me to copy and paste data in the same format regardless of the `<br/>` tag. 
Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: You should try to export your SQL Server results to a .csv file and open it directly in Excel.

Comment: I dont have much permission to this table. For now I 'm running a select query and I'm copying the data from the result tab. Could you tell me how to export just that table? But I'm not sure I have permission for that. I can try. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry @ssdehero, but I do not have experience with MSSQL. I told you to export to .csv because I do that all the time in MySQL, so I imagined that MSSQL should have some way to do that too.

Comment: @juliobetta 1 .. Its oki. I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio. I will try.  Thank you for your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try formatting the string.  For example:

```
SELECT ..., REPLACE([Comment],'<br/>','''<br/>') ... FROM ...
```

OR

```
SELECT ..., REPLACE([Comment],'<br/>','--linebreak--') ... FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Hope this will only change the data in the table. Not the data in the original table.

Comment: I tried this I got this error..
Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I combined your answer with below answer with Convert(Varchar(Max),MyText) function.. It worked.

Comment: @ssdehero -- if it helps, here is the msdn reference for the REPLACE function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it (I don't use the clipboard). In Excel, go to Data - From Other Sources - From SQL Server. Select your database and the smallest table you have (just to save time, we'll change it later).

With the new table selected, choose Connections - Properties - Definitions. Change the Command Type from Table to SQL and the Command Text to whatever your SQL statement is. Click OK.

The SQL Server driver will properly escape the data (I think) that the clipboard will not.

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually do it is to Convert it to varchar(max)

```
select Convert(Varchar(Max),MyText) as MyText from table1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I combined your answer with above answer  with REPLACE function.. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found a solution to my need, which was copy/paste from SQL server management studio to excel with the text containing `<br> ..</br>` (breaking line) resulting extra cell as new line.

**Solution**

1. click the result to file from SSMS instead of the result to grid then save the result.
2. open excel DATA -> FROM TEXT  and locate the file saved from the SSMS result.

With the default delimiter, setting should bring you the basic required COPY/PASTE format from the data grid.